# My monitor keeps going into sleep mode when it reaches the background just before you log in, after booting up

Tags: 13.04, nvidia, monitor, vga

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and it works when I use an LCD television. My graphics card is a GeForce 650 Ti and my monitor is a HP w1907v.

The graphics card works perfectly, the monitor works, the VGA cable works. It's Ubuntu. I have tried changing the screen resolutions but it just stays in sleep mode. (I am currectly using my LCD to work as a second screen so I can see what I am doing). I have tried changing stuff like resolutions on my monitor but I can't even get onto a menu as it just goes into sleep mode instantly.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

use xrandr to diagnose what is going wrong. Read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

I do following command to extend desktop on right side. Use VGA and LVDS identifications which you have on your system. You will get it by `xrandr --current`

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --right-of LVDS-0
```